# Set xdebug.mode to coverage in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: php, unit-testing, azure-devops, xdebug

I need to set `xdebug.mode` to `coverage` to run unit test in Azure Pipeline.

I have tried to set it manually using this task:

```
- script: |
    sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phpdbg /usr/bin/phpdbg$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set php-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar$(phpVersion)
    sudo apt-get install php$(phpVersion)-mysql -y
    sudo apt-get install jq -y
    php -version
    php -i 
    sudo sed -i 's/develop/coverage/g' /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
  displayName: 'Specify PHP Version'
```

but the `xdebug.mode` still in `develop`, and the pipeline fail when run unit test:

> Code coverage needs to be enabled in php.ini by setting 'xdebug.mode' to 'coverage'

Some body can help me please ?

Comment: AFAIK `develop` is the default value for the `xdebug.mode` : https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode. It may not be present in your php.ini at all ... or even included in a separate xdebug.ini file (the case on some Linux setups/distros -- no idea about Azure). **P.S.** You can try overriding it via `XDEBUG_MODE` environment variable if you cannot do that via .ini file.

Comment: You can refer to [this blog](https://blog.adamcameron.me/2020/12/phpunit-get-code-coverage-reporting.html).

Comment: @LazyOne not work for me , i export XDEBUG_MODE as environment variable  but not worked for me

Comment: 1) Do you even have Xdebug installed? I mean that the *"but the xdebug.mode still in develop"* line suggests that you have it .. but your task snipped does not seem to have anything for Xdebug there... 2) What is your Xdebug version? 3) Can you please show the whole Xdebug section of the `phpinfo()` output captured in a same way (a CLI or web page)?

Comment: sorry bro , it's work ! i missing some details

Answer (score 1):

This is how I get it running. Make sure you have the proper path to your php ini file. You may want to thempoarily add that script task to verify:

```yaml
- script: |
    php --ini
  displayName: verify php ini file location
```

```yaml
steps:
  - script: |
      sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php$(phpVersion)
      sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar$(phpVersion)
      sudo update-alternatives --set phpdbg /usr/bin/phpdbg$(phpVersion)
      sudo update-alternatives --set php-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi$(phpVersion)
      sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar$(phpVersion)
      php -version
    displayName: 'Use PHP version $(phpVersion)'
    
  - script: |
      sudo bash -c "echo \"xdebug.mode=coverage\" > /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini"
    displayName: 'Set XDEBUG mode'
```